# OpenSSL's PEM file and Lockbox3 interoperability

Tags: delphi, openssl, rsa, delphi-7, pem

I have a RSA key in a PEM file created with openssl, and Im trying to load it into Lockbox3 (a delphi component) but it seems they are not compatible. In their forums I found this:

*"Only after you nail down all the options used by the other party, both explicit and implicit (which are typically poorly documented), do you have a chance for interoperability."*

So, I'm wondering if someone had made it work.

Comment: Can you name some of the cryptographic libraries you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Lockbox (available from SVN, not the file downloads as yet), provides a Delphi wrapper of OpenSSL's RSA functionality. It can save and load files in PEM format. I hope this satisfies.

The OpenSSL component is marked as experimental at the moment, but it has been tested and seems to work well.

Comment: Hey Sean, can you provide an example?

Comment: The library comes with a demo. (http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/Grok+TurboPower+LockBox)